# Using a HashSet for foreign key objects in ServiceStack OrmLite with SQL Server

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm having to work around a many-to-many database design with a relation object, but I need to make sure there aren't duplicates. I had hoped I could just define the collection of related objects as a HashSet, but ServiceStack doesn't like it. Here's a simplified version of my POCOs I use for OrmLite:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Reference]
    public HashSet<FooToBar> FooToBars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class FooToBar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Foo))]
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    [References(typeof(Bar))]
    public int BarId { get; set; }

    // This is the requirement that makes it a little odd
    public string Option { get; set; }
}
```

Class `Foo` can only have unique `Bar`s with `Option`s related to it. A `HashSet` is great for this from a C# perspective, but ServiceStack is looking for the related entity Id on the `HashSet` type.

Is there any way I can accomplish this that won't make ServiceStack freak out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference type properties need to be a List, you can still have HashSet properties but it can't be a reference property, ie it gets blobbed with the POCO.

Comment: HashSet should be great as a Reference too, don't you think?

Comment: @labilbe HashSet is unordered and to assert equality each type needs to override equality members which will likely be both rarely used and the source of errors. It's easier to just assert List uniqueness before saving.